# Where is an explanation of all the MobaXTerm RDP sizing options?

Tags: remote-desktop, mobaxterm

Thee number of sizing/scaling options for RDP connections on MobaXterm are confusing and I can't seem to find a good explanation for them all.  The options are:

- Enhanced Graphics: yes/no
- Resolution: Fit to window, 640x480, 800x600, 1280x1024, etc.
- Adapt remote DPI: yes/no
- Autoscale: yes/no
- Smart Sizing: yes/no

So, comparing the options for an RDP connection between mRemoteNG, MSTSC, and MobaXterm finds very little correlation.  And if I have a high resolution display and am connecting to Server 2012 or Server 2016 the results can be different with the same settings.

Is there somewhere that I can find an explanation on how these settings relate to each other?  I basically want to set the resolution to 1280x1024 on the remote client and have it scaled to fit the RDP Window.

Comment: Clearly not an answer (thus the comment) but I myself am a lover of MobaXTerm but would never attempt to use the remote desktop functionality as opposed to the apps already built into windows for this.  Is there a reason? I am asking to learn, not criticize.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a full featured RDP app, and it supports multiple tabbed connections, so its either MobaXTerm or mRemoteNG as far as I know (in the free tier).